# Extremely simple foreach and if - can't figure out why it isn't working - PHP

Tags: php, debugging, foreach, if-statement

I've done a million if and foreach's in scripts before, but this one I can't seem to figure out.  It just isn't working...?  Maybe it's one of those things that if you look at it 100 times you won't see the error and need a second set of eyes.  Okay, so, here's the code:

```
private function removeResultsByUID() {
   foreach ($this->searchResults as $key => $value) {
    if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)
        unset($this->searchResults[$key]);
        }
   return;
   }
```

Simple enough, it is part of a forum search program that attempts to remove search results based on a username they might have entered to filter by.  Problem is, it isn't filtering, so I went into test mode and adjusted the code to see what was going on:

```
private function removeResultsByUID() {
    foreach ($this->searchResults as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID']);
                echo ' ';
                var_dump($this->searchUID);
                echo '<br />';
        if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID) {
             echo "This isn't a match";
             unset($this->searchResults[$key]);
                     }
        }
    die();
    return;
    }
```

Okay, so a simple way to test, dump the variables I'm iffing to see what their values are set to (using var_dump instead of echo to ensure they are both string types for my knowledge).  Then I add an echo to the if to see when the if condition triggers.  Then kill the script to view the results.  I toss in some search criteria with a username, the program changes it to a userID based on a table in the DB, every result it grabs from the search that matches adds the author's user ID to the result array.  Here is what I get:

```
string(1) "3" string(1) "3"
string(1) "1" string(1) "3"
string(1) "1" string(1) "3"
string(1) "1" string(1) "3"
```

It looks like the if is never triggering even though the dumped variables the if is using makes it seem as if it should trigger for the last 3 iterations.  I've stared at it for an hour.  What the hell did I do wrong?  I'm going to kick myself for a stupid mistake I'm sure, I just can't see it.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Oh, and as for commentary about why I'm removing search results after the database calls instead of adding a WHERE UID = $this->searchUID - yes, I know that likely would speed it up but I have a reason to do it this way.

Comment: Gotta love when half a dozen eyes spot what you missed.

Comment: Sigh, yeah, it happens more often than I'd like ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `!=` and not `!$x == $y`:

```
if ($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] != $this->searchUID) {
// or: if(!($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)) {
  // your code here
}
```

`!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID']` will either be `true` or `false` (most likely `false`, unless you have an id of "0"). so your comparison turns into `false == $this->searchUID` – not so likely to match.

Comment: It will always be boolean false, because the output of var_dump() gives you "string(1) "1"". Although, I'm not entirely sure why he is storing IDs as strings and not ints. *adds comment*

Comment: @jeremy: http://codepad.org/kicjmXfE, it can also be boolean true ;) i'll edit my answer to reflect the booleanness, where i wrote 0 and 1

Comment: Well, I most definitely take back. Nifty little checking via PHP there. :)

Comment: Yep, I guess I had a misunderstanding of using the ! symbol as I was, I thought I was saying if(condition does NOT equate).  As for the $value['authorUID'] - I thought foreach worked on a copy of the array and so changing the value within it wouldn't change the object's version - or am I wrong about that too?  I guess I could always use a reference on the value.  Anyway, thanks to all the answers, guys.

Comment: @This solution gives the proper answer but it is not very good. Take a look at my solution!

Comment: @adam: you are right, unsetting only works when having the key. i missed that part

Comment: you can still use the ! at the front if you use parens to enclose the entire boolean expression: 
if (! ($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID) )

Comment: @dar7yl: yes i know. that's why there is a comment below the firstif saying `or: if(!(…)) `

Answer (score 1):

I assume that searchResults is an array of array

You loop through each element like so:

```
foreach ($this->searchResults as $key => $value)
```

Then you don't use the value at all:

```
if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)
```

I think you wanted to say:

```
if (value['authorUID'] != $this->searchUID)  // (fixed Boolean logic)
```

and you can further optimize it by using a reference in the foreach:

```
 foreach ($this->searchResults as $key => &$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)
```

You're negating the first term and then comparing to the second term. Add parentheses or use `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You have !$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID']
IF you want them to be equal remove the !

If you want them to not be equal then it should be
if ($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] != $this->searchUID)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the placement of the ! in your if statement?

Won't your if statement equate to:

```
if ([opposite-of]$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] (false) == $this->searchUID (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple logic error in your if statement. This is what you have:

```
if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)
```

Looking at this, you negate $this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] before the comparison.

Negating a string, turns it to false. So you are always checking:

```
if(false == $this->searchUID)
```

I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to check, but that should push you into the right direction of fixing it.

Edit:

As I'm looking, I realized the var dump is 'string(1) "3"'. If this is an ID, wouldn't it make more sense (and be faster) to use simple int, rather than string comparisons?

Comment: They are (MEDINT) in the table, I'm not sure how they got changed around to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
if (!$this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] == $this->searchUID)
```

It should be:

```
if ($this->searchResults[$key]['authorUID'] != $this->searchUID)
```

I'm not 100% sure (didn't check), but if you ! an integer, it returns == 0. IE: an integer is "true" if it's not zero. So you have "!true == integer", or, "false == integer", and since your other integer is non-zero, you have "false == true" as your test.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use ! and if 'authorID' is equal to 'searchUID' and 'authorId' is an array you want to try a simplier, elegant and faster way to loop through your array:

```
if ( ! $this->searchResults [$key] [ 'authorId' ] [ $this->searchUID ] ) {
```

Here is the whole function:

```
private function removeResultsByUID() {
 foreach ( $this->searchResults as $key => $value ) {
    if ( ! $this->searchResults[$key] [ 'authorId' ] [ $this->searchUID ] ) {
         unset($this->searchResults[$key]);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: As you have stated this is more "elegant," I'd like to ask a few questions. By using $this->searchUID, you are assuming that [$key] is an array who's keys are the UID's, however, looking at the code, it appears the keys are named. He wants to compare the value of [$key]['authorID'] to $this->searchUID. Can you explain how this is better / works based on the original (or any of the corrected solutions)?

Comment: @epitaph: your if condition will not work with the array structure suggested by the OP. it checks for something completely different

Comment: @all: Don't panic, I forgot an array but I hope you are getting the meaning!

Comment: Can you please expand your answer, then? I'm all for learning better ways to write code.

Comment: @Jeremy: I have corrected my answer. It´s like using a hash-key. I hope it helps!

Comment: It's still a little on the confusing end. Wouldn't you need ['authorId']'s indexes to be $this->searchUID = $this->searchUID?

Comment: @epitaph: `results[$key]['authorId']` is **not** an array, it's a scalar value (an integer). the OP wants to compare two integers, not if an index in an array is set

Comment: @Jeremy: Like knittl is writing authorid is not an index - but let forget about OP and knittl one moment my example gives the proper answer. Anyway it seems I'm getting haters here I can delete my post!

Comment: I'm not hating, I'm just thoroughly confused as to how this works. Although I do agree, that [$key]['authorId'] is a scalar, and not an array. I did a quick google search and came up empty. Personally, I prefer our solutions as they are simple and straight forward, but I'm completely open to learning how yours works.

Comment: @Jeremy Sorry for the haters, but ok it,s a scalar then scratch this :).